# Metric induced by infinity norm?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The infinity norm is defined as follows:

$||\mathbf{x}||=\max\{|x_1|,...,|x_n|\}$.

Say we have $\mathbb{R}^2$ endowed with $||\ ||_{\infty}$. Then what is $d((2,1),(3,2))$? Is it just $(3,2)$? If so, then how does it make sense to talk about a ball in this metric?

Comment: You appear to not understand what a norm or metric function is!  d(2, 1),  (3, 2)) CANNOT be (3, 2) because the metric (distance) is a NUMBER not a vector or point. The vector from (2, 1) to (3, 2) is (3-2, 2- 1)=  (1, 1).  The max of those two numbers is "1". d((2, 1), (3, 2))= 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A metric is **always** a mapping from some space to $\mathbb R$, so your answer $(3,2)$ cannot be correct. The distance must always be a single number, not a pair of numbers.

That said the answer $d((2,1), (3,2)) = 1$. Why? Well,

> If $\|.\|$ is a norm, then the metric induced by it is defined as $$d(x,y) = \|x-y\|$$

Now, in your case $x=(2,1), y=(3,2)$. The distance between them is $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|$ which is easy to calculate since $x-y$ is easy to calculate.

Comment: So if I'd had $x=(2,1)$ and $y=(4,2)$ then I would have got $d(x,y)=\max\{1,2\}=2$. Thanks!

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt Correct! By the way, the ball in this metric makes sense, but it does have a strange shape, since it is actually a square (all elements of $[-1,1]^2$ are less than $1$ away from $0$. This means that for this metric, the unit ball is "barely" convex.